# In node.js, why does `requiring` an IIFE create a single closure in the global space?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a JavaScript module that looks something like this:

```
const Tools = {};
Tools.log = (function {
    var logPath = '';
    // ... and all the stuff that is returned below
    return {
        setLogPath: setLogPath,
        trace: trace,
        debug: debug,
        info: info,
        warn: warn,
        error: error
    };
})();
module.exports = Tools;
```

I require this module in two files using:

```
var log = require(path/to/module).log;
```

I would have expected each require statement to create a separate closure, but I find that if I call the `setLogPath` method in one file, then the log path in the other file changes as well.

This is actually good for me. But I don't understand why only a single closure is being created.

I was expecting the the Tools.log function to be run every time the `require` statement was used, creating separate closures of the `Tools.log` function within the files where the require statement is used. This is obviously not the case. In these files, the `const Tools = require(path/to/Tools/).log` is in the global namespace if that makes a difference.

How does the require statement work?

This code shows what I was expecting:

```
const A = function() {
    var closureVal = 'a'

    function changeVal(val) {
        closureVal = val;
    };

    function printVal() {
        console.log(closureVal);
    };
    return {
        changeVal: changeVal,
        printVal: printVal
    };
};
var x = A();
x.printVal(); // a
x.changeVal('x');
x.printVal(); // x
var y = A();
y.printVal(); // a
y.changeVal('y')
y.printVal(); // y
x.printVal(); // x
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if I change that test code above to use an IIFE like this:

```
const A = (function() {
    var closureVal = 'a'

    function changeVal(val) {
        closureVal = val;
    };

    function printVal() {
        console.log(closureVal);
    };
    return {
        changeVal: changeVal,
        printVal: printVal
    };
})();
var x = A;
x.printVal(); // a
x.changeVal('x');
x.printVal(); // x
var y = A;
y.printVal(); // x
y.changeVal('y')
y.printVal(); // y
x.printVal(); // y
```

Then I see the same thing as with the require statement. I would expect this because in this test the `A` function is only being run once, with `vars x,y` then assigned to the resultant object as pointers.

But I still don't see the why the same is happening with the require statement, where I would expect the function to be run every time the module is loaded